JMeter - search function advice
If I use the 'search' function in JMeter and the search tree opens.  when I put a string in the Search field and click 'Search All & Expand', all the relevant Requests containing the string get highlighted.
Good so far....
Now when I click on one of the highlighted requests and open the Body Data, I want to be able to see where the string is.  There doesn't appear to be a Find function the highlight the string in the Body Text (which can be huge!).  Does one exist?
I have tried using Ctrl+F to bring up a find function.  No luck.
